# Unit circle shifted upwards so it is tangent the graph of $f(x)=x^{2}$

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

How can we find k so that $x^{2}+(y-k)^{2}$ is tangent to the graph of $f(x)=x^2$?[image: Picture]

Comment: Barely touches is not a mathematic term. Maybe you mean being tangent to it ?

Comment: I think 'touches' suffices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substantial hint:

Suppose you knew $k$. Then at the (right hand) point where the graphs touch -- call it $(a,b)$, you'd know three things:

1. $b = a^2$
2. $a^2 + (b-k)^2 = 1$
3. $\frac{b-k}{a} = \frac{-1}{2a}$

The last follows by drawing a line from $(a, b)$ to the circle center at $(0, k)$. That line has slope $\frac{b-k}{a}$. It's also perpendicular to the tangent line to the parabola at $(a, b)$, which has slope $2a$. And the product of the slopes of perpendicular lines is always $-1$.

Now you just have to solve those three simultaneous equations.

Comment: I got $k=\frac{7}{8}\\$, but when I plot it it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Are you sure that you've made calculations right? I got $k=\frac74$ in my mind (unfortunately I do not have a paper and pen right now)

Comment: When you got $k = 7/8$, what values did you get for $a$ and $b$? Do the resulting values satisfy all three equations? If not, then you made a mistake.

Comment: You could even add your method for arriving at $7/8$ to your question (click on "edit" just below the question itself) so that we might show where you went off the rails.

Comment: Made a mistake. Sorry for bothering. The answer is $\frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: Perhaps you can delete that last comment, so that the next person who wants to do this problem has the same chance as you to actually find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The points of intersection of the parabola and the circle are the solutions of the pair of equations $$y=x^2 \text{ and } x^{2}+(y-k)^{2}=1 $$ or, equivalently,  $$y=x^2 \text{ and } y+(y-k)^{2}=1 $$
The circle is tangent to the parabola if the quadratic equation for $y$ has exactly one solution.